# devise_token_auth in rails 5 API: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, token, devise-token-auth

I have a Rails 5 API project with devise_token_auth gem installed. I also have a vue project using jtoker to aunthenticate to the rails api.

Everytime I send a request from the vue application to register a user I get Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity, here is the rails log:

```
Started POST "/admin_auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-14 17:05:34 -0600
   (0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"dbenjaminrdz@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "config_name"=>"admin", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:8080/register"}
Unpermitted parameter: :config_name
Unpermitted parameter: :config_name
Unpermitted parameter: :config_name
Unpermitted parameter: :config_name
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Admin Exists (1.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = $1 AND "admins"."provider" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "dbenjaminrdz@gmail.com"], ["provider", "email"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 198ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

I am using jtoker as following:

```
Auth.emailSignUp({
    email: payload.email,
    password: payload.password,
    password_confirmation: payload.password_confirmation,
    config: 'admin'
});
```

I have looked online for similar problems but none of the solutions worked. Please help me :(

Comment: I have the same issue, did you found a solution?